# Java. Help figure out why my code doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

here is my code, i can't figure out why it doesn't work. This algorithm have to sort array but when i run it, it retreive me the same array.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BubbleSorted1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] data = {40,20,50,30,10};
        sort(data);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));

    }

    public static void sort(int[] array){
        for(int barrier = array.length-1; barrier >= 0; barrier--){
            for(int index = 0; index < barrier; index++){
                if(array[index] > array[index] + 1){
                    int tmp = array[index];
                    array[index] = array[index + 1];
                    array[index + 1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is a great moment to learn how to use a debugger :)

Comment: The if conditon for swap should have array[index] > array[index + 1])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write `array[index] > array[index] + 1`. This should probably have been `array[index] > array[index + 1]` as the check you do is always false.

Comment: shame for me, it's my inattention. Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo here:

```
if(array[index] > array[index] + 1){
```

I think you meant:

```
if(array[index] > array[index + 1]){
```

The first condition can never be true because a number (the value contained in the `index` of the array) won't never be greater than itself plus one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Only thing You need to change is **IF** condition

```
 public static void sort(int[] array){
                for(int barrier = array.length-1; barrier >= 0; barrier--){
                    for(int index = 0; index < barrier; index++){
                        if(array[index] > array[index+1]){
                            int tmp = array[index];
                            array[index] = array[index + 1];
                            array[index + 1] = tmp;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Explaining *why* there is a problem is our first priority here. Not just handing out the solution. Also, please fix up the formatting!